# Cross-reference to custom float

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I've defined a custom float, but my cross-reference to it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{program}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Program}

\begin{document}

See Listing \ref{prog:hello}.

\begin{program}
  \label{prog:hello}
  \begin{verbatim}

class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Display the string
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{verbatim}
  \caption{The Hello World! program in Java.}
\end{program}

\end{document}
```

As you can see in the output below, the cross-reference to the program listing didn't work. I.e., the number is missing after "See Listing".

[image: LaTex output]

Comment: There is no `\label` after `\caption`

Comment: Ah, that's it. I had the label after \begin{program}. didn't realise it had to be after \caption.

Comment: In conjunction with a `float` and a `\caption` the label must be placed **after** the `\caption` call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `\label` call always after `\caption`, not somewhere before. Using it the wrong counter information is written to the `.aux` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{program}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Program}

\begin{document}

See Listing \ref{prog:hello}.

\begin{program}
  \begin{verbatim}

class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Display the string
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{verbatim}
  \caption{The Hello World! program in Java.}
  \label{prog:hello}
\end{program}

\end{document}
```

[image]